# First frame not getting blur from ffmpeg

Tags: filter, ffmpeg, overlay

I am trying to run a combination of overlay and boxblur filters to blur pixels in human background (using ffmpeg). My command is as follows:

```
ffmpeg -y \
 -ss 00:00:02.000 -t 00:00:02.000 -i Adeel_Abbas_20210423T191428-1X.MP4 \
 -ss 00:00:02.000 -t 00:00:02.000 -i Adeel_Abbas_20210423T191428-1X-SM.MP4 \
-filter_complex " \
[0:v][1:v] alphamerge[fg0]; [0:v]boxblur=luma_radius=3:chroma_radius=0:alpha_radius=0:luma_power=1:chroma_power=0:alpha_power=0[bv0]; [bv0][fg0]overlay,crop=1920:1080:0:78,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[vs0]" -map "[vs0]" \
  -b:v 8709120 -bf 2 -threads 8 -tag:v avc1 -c:v libx264 -preset medium -g 144 -color_primaries bt709 -color_trc bt709 -colorspace smpte170m  output.mp4
```

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/vcjg6ps7j70e330/AAA8giBT77s_02oApy5q1LSVa?dl=0) are sample files that can be used to perfectly reproduce this issue.

Using ffmpeg-5.0 the background in first frame will not get blur applied but successive frames will get blurred properly. Can someone please help

Comment: Does it work if you move `-ss` to output? You can wait for extra 2-seconds worth of encoding time. Other than that, you have a lot of filters involved, I'd do some "elimination filtering" to identify who's causing this behavior.

Comment: It does not happen then. But it is preferable to use seek operation on input since seeking on input at the end for large files is more performant than seeking on output.

Answer (score 0):

Only happens if I seek from random places in original file using `-ss 00:00:02.000 -t 00:00:02.000` command. If I start processing from beginning of file by omitting `-ss` flag, everything looks good.